# Red Hat and Likewise

Tags: linux, redhat, likewise-open, rhn

Is likewise available via RHN?

I've used likewise-open a few times in ubuntu on small projects but looking at it again for a larger project. I have seen press releases regarding the support of likewise and redhat but can't find it in RHN.

The likewise enterprise site offers 'free downloads' of the open version in RPM format but I'd prefer to have something manged via RHN as that is the general policy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never has been in the past. [This thread](http://www.likewise.com/community/index.php/forums/viewthread/993/#2971) leads me to believe that it isn't in RHEL6 either.

I suspect that you would either need to run your own Satellite (or Spacewalk) server to push out applications. If you wanted to pull them from the client, you'd need an internal YUM repo and a configuration management solution (like puppet, chef, or CFengine) to have them install the the packages and keep them up to date.

Someone else may know: is it possible to run arbitrary commands on servers subscribed to certain channels using RHN? If so, you may be able to make a server pull from an internal YUM repo without a 3rd party configuration management solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's obvious but needed to hear it. We run mrepo and puppet. Ideally I'd like to configure mrepo to get the rpm regularly from likewise since the package isn't available in RHN. But this is a topic for research and if necessary another post.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom .repo files for yum to pull from internally. The best approach would be to use Satellite to create custom channels and include the .rpm files that way. Going this route, you could also push the configuration via satellite/spacewalk configuration management, but you'll need the add-ons for that as well.

BTW - Likewise Open is now owned by [BeyondTrust](http://beyondtrust.com) and has been rebranded PowerBroker Identity Services (PBIS) - they do still put out the "Open" product under the name Likewise-Open.